# How to turn Auto-Lock to Never in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is there any Swift command to actually set the Auto-Lock to Never or a specific time period? I want to create a simple app that only has two buttons: one is to set the Auto-Lock to Never and the other one is to set it back to iOS default (1 min).

So when a user open this app and tap the Never button, s/he can open other apps but the iPhone or iPad will never auto lock while running the other apps. If s/he is done with other apps, s/he can open this app again and tap the Default button to set the Auto-Lock back to 1 min.

I understand this can be done from the Settings but I am just curious how I can do it from the backend using Swift.

I am new to Swift, btw.

Thanks much!

Comment: Can’t be done in iOS using public APIs.

Comment: You can prevent the screen from going to sleep only if user is inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

> So when a user open this app and tap the Never button, s/he can open other apps but the iPhone or iPad will never auto lock while running the other apps

You can't do that. *You are sandboxed.* You cannot affect what happens to the user while running some other app.

Answer (score -1):

When app is open, try to disable the idleTimer in viewDidLoad

> UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

When app is closed to open other apps, try  to -enable again idleTimer when yourViewController disappears, so put this in viewDidDisappear

> UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false

Answer (score -2):

You need to make use of this API call to set the idle timer disable and enable. 
This is in objective-C. Just convert it to swift. The API is available in UIApplication.h

-(void) onApplicationDidActivate:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
}

-(void) onApplicationWillDeactivate
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
}

Comment: `setIdleTimerDisabled` only affects the app that calls it.